# iOS UIButtons inside prototype cell not clickable

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I am building my first iphone app (IOS6 compatible, mostly running on IOS 7), and I've gotten stuck on enabling buttons inside a prototype cell. My application loads data from a rest server into a table view, where each cell is meant to have 3 buttons (sharing).

Everything works smoothly, and the buttons do display (they have images, but I've tried with text only), except the buttons aren't clickable/do not call touch up event and do not change appearance/highlight on mouse down. The 3 buttons are inside a toolbar, inside a view which is inside the content view.

I have tried the following with no success:

1. Moved the buttons directly into the content view
2. Moved the buttons to the front (with code as well as in the storyboard)
3. No action is called, tried placing action function into both the controller and the cell.
4. User interaction is enabled on all levels
5. Removed the buttons from the storyboard, and loaded them "manually"/code in the table controller, inside cellForRowAtIndexPath function.

I have connected the buttons to an action function, that currently only displays some text in the console.

(I'm not able to upload screenshot, due to this being a new account, but I will post a link to it at some point if needed).

All help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are the buttons set to `enabled` in interface builder? Where do the actions live? In the cell class, or the class that owns the table view?

Comment: All buttons are enabled, I have tried implementing the action functions in both (one at a time) controller class and cell class, no luck. It also doesn't seem like the button calls any action, since they don't behave as other buttons in the app (e.g. the button doesn't look pressed when clicking on it).

Comment: Usually, this is caused by the buttons being outside the bounds of their superview. Try giving the superview a background color to make sure the buttons are within it.

Comment: I tried that, the buttons seem correctly positioned. I also tried removing everything except the contentview and one of the buttons, still not working. Perhaps I'm using an option somewhere that I shouldn't.

Comment: @bazman I have the same issue. Tried everything suggested in Stackoverflow with no luck. Did you find a solution?